# Unable to upload large file using SFTP with .net core

Tags: c#, .net-core, sftp, large-files, ssh.net

I'm trying to upload large file (about 350 MB) to an SFTP server using SSH.NET with .Net Core, but it's not fully uploaded!, when i check the SFTP server i see file size 15 or 20 MB only! and the rest of file data are lost!

using the following code:

```
       try
            {
                using (_sftp)
                {
                    _sftp.Connect();
                    _sftp.ChangeDirectory("/remote/dir/");
                    var fullPath = _configuration["SftpFiles"];
                    using (var uploadFileStream = File.OpenRead(fullPath + fileName))
                    {
                        _sftp.UploadFile(uploadFileStream, fileName, true);
                    }
                    _sftp.Disconnect();
                }
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return false;
            }
```

any help will be great.

Comment: Try setting the buffer size to various values. I've seen that before. Alternatively, get an SftpFileStream  to the remote file and use CopyTo between the streams.

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 if there's a code example it will be great.

Comment: Your problem is either the server or your client. i would try to rule one of those out

Comment: Does your code throw any exception (not that you silently ignore all exceptions). + Can you upload a full file using any (GUI/commandline) SFTP client?